# In Python, how to make a wrapper work for both class and static methods

Tags: python

I have several methods called `parse` which are either static or class methods. In both cases, I would like them to return `None` if the input is `None`. To this end, I tried to define the following wrapper `maybe`:

```
import types

def maybe(function):
    if type(function) == types.FunctionType:
        def wrapped_function(arg, **kwargs):
            return function(arg, **kwargs) if arg is not None else None
        return wrapped_function
    elif type(function) == types.MethodType:
        def wrapped_function(cls, arg, **kwargs):
            return function(cls, arg, **kwargs) if arg is not None else None
        return wrapped_function
    else:
        raise TypeError("The 'maybe' wrapper can wrap either a function or a method.")
```

Here is an example use case with some tests to accompany it:

```
import pytest

class Resource(object):
    @classmethod
    @maybe
    def parse_class(cls, string):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    @maybe
    def parse_static(string):
        pass


'''Tests'''
def test_maybe_parse_class():
    assert Resource.parse_class(None) == None

def test_maybe_parse_static():
    assert Resource.parse_static(None) == None


if __name__ == "__main__":
    pytest.main([__file__])
```

The problem is that the second test fails with a

```
TypeError: wrapped_function() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

It seems that Python is trying to evaluate or 'check' the contents of the `if type(function) == types.FunctionType` block, even though I've verified through a `print` statement that Boolean is `False`.

How can I make this wrapper work in both tests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force the `maybe` annotation to be done after the static or class annotation (putting it above in the code). Then you can examine the annotation of the function/descriptor and decide what to do with it. eg.

```
def maybe(wrapped):

    if isinstance(wrapped, classmethod):
        original_function = wrapped.__func__

        @classmethod
        def wrapper(cls, arg):
            if arg is None:
                return None
            else:
                return original_function(cls, arg)
        return wrapper

    elif isinstance(wrapped, staticmethod):
        original_function = wrapped.__func__

        @staticmethod
        def wrapper(arg):
            if arg is None:
                return None
            else:
                return original_function(arg)
        return wrapper

    raise TypeError("expected classmethod or staticmethod")

class Resource(object):
    @maybe
    @classmethod
    def parse_class(cls, arg):
        return "not none"

    @maybe
    @staticmethod
    def parse_static(arg):
        return "not none"
```

This is for python 3. It appears you may have python 2. So it's not 100% guaranteed to work. You might have to go to more work to get the original function out of the classmethod obj

Answer (score 1):

Your method actually works, excepted that you made a simple typing mistake, by typing `arg` instead of `*arg`.  For the `classmethod`, an extra argument will be passed which is the `cls` argument and just `arg` isn't designed to take both the `cls` and the `None` so the error occurred. `arg`and `*arg` indeed have different meanings, just `arg` stands for a positional argument at the given position while `*arg` takes every leftover argument not caught by the positional arguments. It operates the same way as `**kwargs` taking all leftover keyword arguments.

So you should change `maybe` to this:

```
import types

def maybe(function):
    if type(function) == types.FunctionType:
        def wrapped_function(*arg, **kwargs): # change here
            return function(*arg, **kwargs) if arg is not None else None # change here
        return wrapped_function
    elif type(function) == types.MethodType:
        def wrapped_function(cls, *arg, **kwargs): # change here
            return function(cls, *arg, **kwargs) if arg is not None else None # and change here
        return wrapped_function
    else:
        raise TypeError("The 'maybe' wrapper can wrap either a function or a method.")
```